# MATLAB error: input argument undefined

Tags: matlab

I've got a small MATLAB function I'm attempting to run by calling it from the command line, as follows:

```
>> [x, y , true_HF, max_F]=main (10)
```

However, when run, I end up with an error:

```
??? Input argument "HF" is undefined.
```

Searching online has yielded a bunch of results for people forgetting the argument, which I don't believe I'm doing (I'm a newb at this stuff).

For reference, my "main" function:

```
function [ x, y, true_HF, max_F ] = main(HF)
    global Data
    Data = [];
    close all
    true_HF = fzero ( diff_L, HF );
    [x,y] = find_xy ( true_HF );
    final_graphs()
    max_F = max_force ( y, true_HF );
end
```

Additionally, a "whos" prior to the offending line (That is, "true_HF = fzero ( diff_L, HF );"), shows that the variable HF is set.

Any MATLAB geniuses out there who know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: where does `diff_L` come from?

Comment: It's a function defined in another file.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there are other functions with the same name that are higher on your [path](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_env/br7ppws-1.html):

```
>> which main -all
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's three ideas to try:

First, I occasionally run into an issue where the function called from the command line is the previous version.  Make sure you've saved the file.  For instance if you had originally written the file with the first line

```
function [ x, y, true_HF, max_F ] = main(other_variable, HF)
```

You'd have to save to call main(10) else, you'd get the undefined HF message

The second possibility: if you have re-saved it, then check to make sure the copy you're editing is in the current directory for the command window.  Having several functions with the same name separated into different folders can lead to some unexpected behavior.  Just keep this in mind if you're working with, for example, ~/new_function/main.m as well as ~/old_function/main.m.

Lastly, you can check if the call to fzero is valid by making the following changes for testing purposes only:

```
function [ x, y, true_HF, max_F ] = main(HF)
%% <- "%%" starts a new cell in the program
    HF = 10 % type this in for testing purposes
    % commented out because we are going to evaluate the code inside the current workspace    
    % global Data 
    % Data = [];
    close all
    true_HF = fzero ( diff_L, HF ); % diff_L will have to be in the current workspace variables
    [x,y] = find_xy ( true_HF );
    final_graphs()
    max_F = max_force ( y, true_HF );
%% <- end the cell
end
```

Now, with your cursor in between the two "%%" signs press ctrl-return.  This will evaluate the code in the cell (the code between the two "%%").

Let us know about your progress.

--Andrew